# Are the isoparametric cones the only known examples of minimizing hypercones?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

After searching the literature for a long time, it seems to me that the only known examples of area minimizing hypercones are isoparametric cones and their products with $\Bbb R^k$. By isoparametric cone, I mean the cone over a minimal isoparametric hypersurface in $S^n$. I feel like the isoparametric cones are very special e.g. they all have constant length of second fundamental form and it is an integer. I am wondering is there any other area minimizing hypercones? What is the current status on constructing examples of area minimizing cones?